# Different UI features for Logged In and Unlogged users

Tags: java, android, interface

I have ViewPager that has 3 tabs. Tab(2) includes 1 nested fragment (A). Tab(3) includes 2 nested fragments (B) --> (C).

```
Tab(1)
Tab(2) --> (A) 
Tab(3) --> (B) --> (C)
```

1. Goal: Be able to display additional elements inside of (A),
   for Logged In users.
2. Ideas: Instead of doing multiple checks if user is being logged in, I
   could try to create a interface called *"ListOfEventsInterface"*
   with all needed functions declared, then create 2x fragments
   *"ListOfEventsLogged"* & *"ListOfEventsUnlogged"* that will implement those functions so my code looks clean.

What would be your suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to not create multiple fragments, rather contain a single activity, than will host multiple fragments and populate the fragment that you were original planning to implement with multiple well structured view elements rather than nested fragments. Introducing multiple fragments will cause chaos as fragments are not just views but rather lifecycle elements.

Secondly, you are thinking correct of implementing two classes as that will implement 'Interface Segregation Principle', giving your application a better structure and less error prone as classes will not depend on something that they do not need. Creating `ListOfEventsInterface` will create application-wide contract, which in theory is good to keep track of your application's public API, but in practice would not suffice. Rather break this Interface into smaller, more manageable interfaces.

Comment: Hello Karan, I simplified my model for the sake of clarity but it has lots of fragments. I updated my post with my actual UI model. What would be your first suggestion with this additional information? Thanks

Comment: You are mixing Fragment's and ViewPager's implementation. What i am trying to understand is why you want to "Nest" fragments? Also, which ViewPager are you using, 1.0 or 2.0? because 2.0 works with an adapter, whereas 1.0 takes fragments.

Comment: The app I'm working at contains a viewPager v1.0. I'm keeping it in just one activity because I want to have the TabLayout on top of my screen for the whole app's lifecycle.

Comment: In that case, yout ViewPager's children would be fragments. I would suggest creating as many fragments as you want based on the number of your pages you need in your viewPager. If you want to optimize your viewPager, and most of the "pages" in your viewPager are gonna have same layout, which usually is the case, then i would suggest to create only a single fragment, and them inject different datas in that fragment. Always prefer to not nest your fragments and treat them as layouts BUT with lifecycles.